# Filter NSArray of NSDictionary with specific key's value

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have a NSArray of NSDictionary which is like the following.

```
({
  a = 'one'
  b = 'two'
},
{
  a = 'ten'
  b = 'eleven'
})
```

How can I filter all values of key 'b' which will eventually return me a NSArray like this,

```
('two','eleven')
```

Can it be done with just using NSPredicate without having to loop?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it with single method in NSArray:

```
NSArray *resultArray = [yourArray valueForKey:@"b"];
```

Comment: @MinSoe to understand how this works look at the docs for [NSArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) for the method `valueForKey:`